# Pick 3 Gumballs

Tags: probability

A gumball machine is full of gumballs. There are 7 different colors equally distributed. Each time the handle is turned, 3 gumballs are dispensed. A "jackpot" is defined as all 3 gumballs the same color. The gumballs are replaced after each turn.

1. How many turns are expected between each jackpot?
2. How many turns are expected for two consecutive jackpots of the same color?
3. How many turns are expected for three consecutive jackpots of the same color?

For question 2 and 3, there can be any number of turns in between consecutive jackpots, the jackpots just need to be the same color.

Comment: What have you tried? You should at least have some intuition for #1

Comment: I think there is an unanswered question about the number of gumballs, but I suppose we can assume so many that one coming out of the machine doesn't affect the overall distribution. 

It might make sense for you to think about the number of possible outcomes there are and start moving from there.

Comment: Yes assume infinite number of gumballs. #1 seems fairly straightforward, probability for a single jackpot is 1/7*1/7 = 1/49. This happens to be a real scenario, and the last 3 jackpots were all the same color.

Comment: You are correct that the probability that an individual turn is a jackpot is $\frac{1}{49}$.  Now... do you know about how to find the expected value for the number of turns until you get a jackpot given that information?

Comment: I do not... and perhaps it would inform the answers for #2 and #3. Is the better question: What is the probability of #2 and #3? Then determine expected value for number of turns.

Comment: The end result for #1 is rather convenient.  For #2 and #3, it isn't nearly as convenient.  For #1, if the probability of success is $p$, then it takes $\frac{1}{p}$ attempts on average until you get a success, so in this case $49$.  This can be calculated directly as $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot (1-p)^{n-1}p$.  For the remaining, I don't recognize the result immediately, and don't know if it will simplify nicely, but you should be able to come up with an infinite summation for it by applying definitions directly and coming up with the pdf for the random variable.

Comment: The phrasing of #2,#3 however feels very strange... like you don't know what the word "consecutive" means.  It usually means that there are no turns inbetween eachother.

Comment: Agree "consecutive" might not be the correct word. Here's another way to ask the question: How many turns are expected to get three jackpots AND those three jackpots are the same color?

Answer (score 0):

for 1: $P = (n/7n)^3$ or $1/343$ the same as selecting 3 red balls in sequence one at a time. If you turn the handle $343$ times you'll likely hit a jackpot but not guaranteed.

Comment: Is that true? It doesn't sound like they are looking for a particular jackpot color so it could be one of any of the 7 colors....

Comment: Yes your right. I should have said 3 of the same color and that ball to be put back in the machine each time, and for n >= 3

Comment: For 2 consecutive jackpots there would be a probability of P^2 and for 3, P^3 but he said there can be any number of turns between consecutive jackpots which confused me. You need at least 1/(P^2) turns for 2 jackpots in a row

Answer (score 0):

Based on some great feedback, I believe the answer(s) are as follows:

1. How many turns are expected between each jackpot?

First gumball can be any color. Probability of second gumball same color is 1/7. Probability of third gumball same color is 1/7. Therefore probability = 1/7*1/7 = 1/49. Expected turns = 49.

2. How many turns are expected for two consecutive jackpots of the same color?

Answer #1 established probability of getting a jackpot on any turn is 1/49. First jackpot can be any color. Probability of second jackpot same color is 1/7. Therefore probability = 1/49*1/7 = 1/343. Expected turns = 343.

3. How many turns are expected for three consecutive jackpots of the same color?

Answer #1 established probability of getting a jackpot on any turn is 1/49. First jackpot can be any color. Probability of second jackpot same color is 1/7. Probability of third jackpot same color is 1/7. Therefore probability = 1/49*1/7*1/7 = 1/2,401. Expected turns = 2,401.

Here's the amazing thing. We already had three consecutive jackpots that were blue. This generated a little excitement over the weekend, and we decided to go for a fourth jackpot. It took 74 turns... and it was blue. The probability of four consecutive jackpots same color = 1/49*1/7*1/7*1/7 = 1/16,807.

No fifth jackpot yet. The probability of another blue jackpot is 1/343. The probability of five consecutive jackpots same color is 1/117,649.